# How to load Google Map in Materialize Modal?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, materialize

I am using `materializecss` and the problem is that Google Map not loading in materialize modal. But other than modal, its working fine. I did everything what i have to do. Any solution for this problem?

**Update:**

> I found the solution for my problem. Actually i was using multiple
>   view in that modal and placed my map div back of one div using
>   `ng-show`. It causes my map to not display. But placing map div in
>   front of all other div fixed my issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the modal shows up, it re-sizes its content to fit into it. So your Google map component's size is changed and as a result, it just needs to be refreshed.

Just add the following code in your `<script>` tag.

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    ready: function() {
        var map = document.getElementById("googleMap");
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }
});
```

That should do it :)

**=== EDIT ===**

I've added a sample for what i think might help you. This sample initializes the map object when the page loads, and it uses the same object in the model.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
                ready: function () {
                    var map = document.getElementById("googleMap");
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="#mapmodel" class="modal-trigger blue z-depth-1 waves-effect waves-light btn-floating">
        <i class="red material-icons">location_on</i>
    </a> 

    <div id="mapmodel" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Test</h4>
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="red modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Got it</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i found the solution. but problem not fully solved. when i open a modal and if there is no map present in that page means map is loading in modal. but if there is already map present in that page means, map not loading in modal. just a gray color background with zoom control is displaying. how to fix this????

Comment: add one map div in body section and then open the modal and see. Map will not display properly in modal. This is my problem.

Comment: waiting for the solution. Please help me to solve this issue. :( @Vijay

Comment: Could you send your exact code which is causing the problem? I tried the way you said and it's working in my case..

Comment: Dude, it'd be nice if you sent your code so I could inspect it.

Comment: actually i'm using ng-view to bind partial view. So pls understand me dude. just add map div in body section and also add map div in modal. Then open modal in that page. You wont get map in modal. But if you open modal in some other page in which that page contains no map means, modal will show map without any problem.

Comment: All right, correct me if i'm not mistaken. So you mean just create one more instance of a map object, and display it in a map div inside body section, along with the previous map div which shows inside model? (total two map objects binded to two map divs both maps in the same page one in body section and other in model).. just that?

Comment: Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2oRIgl?p=info) for you. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: perfect dude. Thanks a lot for your solution. I'll try and let you know whether worked in my proj or not. :)

Comment: I dont know where to put this code in `angularjs` having different controllers and passing different `latlng` to map show places. I'm new to web development. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Okay, make sure you have called the .leanModel() method the way i mentioned. Because if you do not implement the 'ready' function, i noticed that your model map will remain gray colored without showing any map. So recheck that you have properly implemented the leanModal() method. And please vote up the answer if you feel my answer has helped so far :)

Comment: Thanks for the vote. So finally it worked in your project?

Comment: nope. :( i did everything to make it work. but still no success.

Comment: Well, in that case double check your call to leanModel(); thats all i can help you with, without your code... :)

Comment: I found the solution for my problem. Actually i was using multiple view in that modal and placed my map div back of one div using `ng-show`. It causes my map to not display. But placing map div in front of all other div fixed my issue. :)

Comment: great!  glad u found it :)